# How can I split up a document into two by even and odd pages?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer, docx

I would like to split up a text document into two documents where one contains only the odd pages and the other contains only the even pages. The document is a `docx` but the exact format is not important. I can open it with Word 2010 and LibreOffice and I could save it as something else if necessary.

If anyone wonders why the heck: I translated a large number of article descriptions, each on one page, and put the translation on the next page. Now I want to create one document with all German texts and another one with all English texts.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a couple of macros:

1. make two copies of your document, one to contain the even pages and
   one to contain the odd pages
2. open the odd page document
3. run the following VBA macro

   Sub DeleteEvenPages()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim pg As Integer
   Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToLast
   pg = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
   If (pg Mod 2) = 1 Then
     Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToPrevious
     pg = pg - 1
   End If
   For i = pg To 2 Step -2
     ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Select
     Selection.Delete
     Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToPrevious
     Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToPrevious
   Next
   End Sub
4. save and close the document
5. open the even page document
6. run the following macro

   Sub DeleteOddPages()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim pg As Integer
   Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToLast
   pg = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
   If (pg Mod 2) = 0 Then
     Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToPrevious
     pg = pg - 1
   End If
   For i = pg To 1 Step -2
     ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Select
     Selection.Delete
     Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToPrevious
     Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToPrevious
   Next
   End Sub
7. Save the even page document.

Comment: Given the requirements, I think this is the best answer so far but keep in mind that this will act strangely if there are items such as tables split across multiple pages.

Comment: @Joel Taylor-Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are editing in the original document but need two separate documents for distribution you could print to PDF using something like CutePDF and select "odd pages only" when printing. Then print again and select even pages only.

[image: Print View]

Comment: I had this idea as well, but unfortunately I need the result in some kind of editable text format.

Answer (score 0):

How many pages is it?  It's more than likely going to have to be a manual effort.  What I would do would be to make a copy of the original file and then on the copy delete out the english text and save that as your english version.  Then make another copy and delete out the german text.

Next time use 2 monitors and open up 2 instances of Word and do the translation into a new document.  If you don't have dual monitors use windows left arrow and windows right arrow so you can see both instances of word.

Comment: Around 70 pages. Yes, that would have been smarter.